# Problem Importing Multiple `.wls` Files From Parent Directory

Tags: import

Inside a Wolfram Script file, I'm trying to import another `.wls` file that's in a parent directory. More specifically, I'm trying to import `common-methods.wls` and `common-methods-old.wls` from `atom-block.wls` (file structure below). A problem occurs when I try to import both files, but not one.

Here's how my folder structure looks:

```
atom-colors
    atom-block.wls
    atom-classification.wls
common-methods.wls
common-methods-old.wls
```

As aforementioned, I try to import from `atom-block.wls`

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
(* ::Package:: *)

(* Sets current directory *)
x=FileNameSplit@$InputFileName;SetDirectory@FileNameJoin@Delete[x, Length@x];

Export["thing.txt", "content"];

Print@Directory[];
Import@FileNameJoin[{ParentDirectory[], "./common-methods-old.wls"}];
Print@Directory[];
Import@FileNameJoin[{ParentDirectory[], "./common-methods.wls"}];
Print@Directory[];

Export[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "thing3.txt"}], "content"];
```

The fifth line gets the parent directory of `atom-block`, the file that is being executed. I did this so `Directory[]` yields the same result when executing via `wolframscript -script ./atom-colors/atom-block.wls` or `wolframscript -script ./atom-block.wls`.

The third print statement prints something strange. The console output is logged below.

```
C:\...\wolfram\atom-colors
C:\...\wolfram\atom-colors
C:\...\wolfram
```

I tried to find why the third print statement prints `C:\...\wolfram` (instead of `C:\...\wolfram\atom-colors`) while the second does not. The documentation says `FileNameJoin[]` joins names of file names, and does not actually change directories. Additionally, `ParentDirectory[]` only *gives* the parent of the current working directory. Besides, I would think the second and third print statements would be the same anyways.

Consequentially, the folder structure after running my program is the following:

```
atom-colors
    atom-block.wls
    atom-classification.wls
    thing.txt
common-methods.wls
common-methods-old.wls
thing3.txt
```

I understand I can use `ResetDirectory[]` to but a bandage over this issue, but the problem at hand really mystifies me and seems to be a much bigger concept that I don't understand. Any help is appreciated! Thanks, Edwin.

Comment: is `SetDirectory @ DirectoryName @ $InputFileName` what you are doing in the 5th line?

Comment: Don't we need to know what is inside `common-methods.wls` to be sure that it isn't changing `Directory[]`?

Comment: @Kuba Oh my gosh! Yes SetDirectory@DirectoryName@$InputFileName is exactly what I was going for. And you're right, `common-methods.wls` was changing the directory. I feel upset because I was stuck on this simple error for many days, trying to fix it the wrong way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am glad the problem is solved, good luck.